# Vaadin UI freeze occasionally

Tags: vaadin

I have an UI with a table and around 10 columns. One columns is define as a textfield. You can input a number and a service selects data from database and fills in the additional information. Sometimes my UI freeze and I have to reload the application. I cannot find something in the log files. 
Can anybody give me a hint where the problem could be?

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? Does the browser stop to respond? Have you a printscreen of such a case?

Comment: Maybe try to reproduce the issue by a SSCCE. It sometimes helps to get the cause of the problem.

Comment: also enable debug mode in vaadin and see in the console tab in firefox whether you get some error messages